# XSLT total and Subtotal

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML:

```
<Forms>
  <Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" />
  <Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" />
  <Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" LDATE="Jul" />
  <Form PRONME="Air Prospect Name" PPRONME="0" NACRES="1" />
  <Form PRONME="Air Prospect Name" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="1" />
  <Total PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="3000"  NACRES="6" />
  <Total PRONME="Air Prospect Name" PPRONME="0" NACRES="2" TBONUSP="1000"  />
</Forms>
```

I want to print the Form Elements into one group after that I want to print the Total of that group, for example:

```
<Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" />
<Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" />
<Form PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" LDATE="Jul" />
```

after reading this group i want to print

```
<Total PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="3000"  NACRES="6" />
```

Based on PRONME I want to Group...
Using XSLT 1.0

Comment: What XSLT version do you use?

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question somewhat – please verify. It would help if you defined what makes a "group" (currently I would *guess* the value of the `PRONME` attribute).

Comment: Based on PRONME I want to Group... Using XSLT 1.0.. Please Help Me how to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display in HTML format you can use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="Form" use="@PRONME"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">td,th{border:1px solid black}</style>
      </head>
      <table style="border:solid 1px black;border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr>
          <th>PRONME</th>
          <th>PPRONME</th>
          <th>TBONUSP</th>
          <th>NACRES</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Form[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', @PRONME))]"/>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Form">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@PRONME"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@PPRONME"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP)"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@NACRES)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

[image]

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">td,th{border:1px solid black}</style>
      </head>
      <table style="border:solid 1px black;border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr>
          <th>PRONME</th>
          <th>PPRONME</th>
          <th>TBONUSP</th>
          <th>NACRES</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Total"/>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Total">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]"/>

    <tr style="color:red">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@PRONME"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@PPRONME"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@TBONUSP"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@NACRES"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Form">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@PRONME"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@PPRONME"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@TBONUSP"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@NACRES"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Above is my Code but my inputxml has been changed to Given format at the Beginning so i needed help to read different tag elements....

Comment: @Rocky111, Update your question, not my answer.

Comment: in the Place of Red Line I want to Print the <total > elements attributes..by matching ProNME ."sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP)" i don't want do calculation from XSLT...Because i already have XML with <total> Element friend..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="Form" use="@PRONME"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Form[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', @PRONME))]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Form">
    <Total PRONME="{@PRONME}" PPRONME="{@PPRONME}" 
           TBONUSP="{sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP)}"
           NACRES="{sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@NACRES)}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Total PRONME="Air Prospect 2" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="3000" NACRES="6" />
<Total PRONME="Air Prospect Name" PPRONME="0" TBONUSP="1000" NACRES="2" />
```

Comment: I tried in "XML notepad" with the code you gave.. but i did't get any output.. need to change anything...? how do i check otherwise...i am very new to this help me out..

Comment: @Rocky111, I don't use "XML notepad". I think you have to set input XML and XSL template. Then run transformation process. I have no idea, does "XML notepad" save output XML to file or show on screen.

Comment: @Rocky111, If it saves to file with extension `.htm` and you open this file in browser, than you will see anything, but you can view page source, which will be as my provided output.

Comment: I added <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xsl"?> to XML.... output should come right...???

Comment: @Rocky111, Open in browser, e.g. IE you XML. You will see blank screen that it is because is has no HTML content to display.

Comment: @Rocky111, See my 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799400/xslt-total-and-subtotal/6799950#6799950.

Comment: I don't want to do the sum from the XSlT... SUM() i'll get from the XML itself.. i want to Print a group.. after that total of that group... 2nd group total of that group....Based on the name of the PRONME....See my XML at Top...Hope You have the Idea for this.....

Comment: @Rocky111, Can you provide output result in HTML or image?

Comment: in the Place of Red Line I want to Print the <total > elements attributes..by matching ProNME ...i don't want do calculation from XSLT...Because i already have XML with <total> Element friend..

Comment: Hi Can u look at this..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881943/xslt-lookup-table-help